# Questions about 3D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, multidimensional-array

[image: my code and my output]

I use empty to assume that i don't know howmany items stored in the arrays[cr. Kinjal Dixit]

Comment: Please don't post your code as a screenshot!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing your array out-of-bounds.

*eg*

```
char name[HAVE_DISCOUNT][HAVENT_DISCOUNT][MAX_LENGTH];

//...
sscanf( input, "%s", name[i][HAVENT_DISCOUNT] );  // <-- out of bounds
```

You have to index your array with positive integers less than the size of that dimension.

Perhaps you wanted something like this:

```
typedef enum {
    HAVE_DISCOUNT,
    HAVENT_DISCOUNT,
    NUM_DISCOUNT_TYPES
} DiscountType;

const int MAX_NAMES = 32;

char name[MAX_NAMES][NUM_DISCOUNT_TYPES][MAX_LENGTH];

// etc...
```